# How to detect Tablets in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC application how can I detect whether the user is using the Tablet device or the Mobile device?

Please I am looking for a no media queries solution.

Comment: Why do you want to detect a tablet or other mobile device?

Comment: We have separate views for phones and separate views for tablet devices?

Comment: What is a tablet? Is it a device between X and Y screen size in inches? Is it a device with M pixels per inch and N pixels?

Comment: I guess that is a good question that what exactly classify as a Tablet. The main reason for detecting the diff is that the layout changes between the phones and large sized tablets (iPads).

Comment: CSS media queries? ASP.NET MVC is a web application framework so no reason CSS and JavaScript can't be used the same way as anywhere else.

Comment: NO CSS Media Queries!

Comment: Calm down! And write that in your question if you dont want to use media queries.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built-in for ASP.Net (*you can test Request.UserAgent, but you need to know more info about specific device*), you could detect the device client-side(with the help of something like [**web.wurfl.io**](http://web.wurfl.io/#learnmore)) then parametrize your controllers, otherwise, if you are looking for a pure server-side solution, you could try [**WURFL**](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/wurfl.php) => Wireless Universal Resource FiLe

> WURFL is a Device Description Repository (DDR), i.e. a framework that
>   enables applications to map HTTP requests to a description of the
>   capability of the mobile device that requests the page. In this
>   regard, WURFL pre-dates the time when the DDR term was coined and
>   could arguably be caracterized as the first DDR. In the last year,
>   WURFL role has expended from being a DDR for mobile devices to being a
>   framework to detect every HTTP client worth recognizing.

Thanks to WURFL, mobile web sites and application can:

- programmatically abstract away devices differences
- avoid the need to modify applications whenever a new device ships
- avoid the need to track new devices on the market

> WURFL is a global database of all devices and the API to tap that
>   information programmatically.